# Wordpress frontend upload not working for logged out users

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, form-data

I am using the code below to upload files to Wordpress from a frontend form and get their metadata, which is used to populate fields etc:

```
var formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("action", "upload-attachment");
      var fileInputElement = document.getElementById("entryfile");
      formData.append("async-upload", fileInputElement.files[0]);
      formData.append("name", fileInputElement.files[0].name);
      formData.append("_wpnonce", upload_nonce);
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200){
          console.log(xhr.responseText);             
        }
      }
      xhr.open("POST","wp-admin/async-upload.php",true);
      xhr.send(formData);
```

However, this code only works for logged-in users. If the visitor is not logged in, the console logs a redirect that looks like:

```
wp-login.php?redirect_to=http:// ...
```

Why doesn't this work? Is there a workaround for this?

** UPDATE: **
I ended up using formData to upload the file. However, I cannot seem to be able to handle it after that point. Here is the code I am using in my php ajax handler:

```
if ($_FILES) {
    foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
      if ($_FILES[$file]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        echo json_encode("upload error : " . $_FILES[$file]['error']);
        exit;
      }
      $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file, 0 );
    }
  }
```

I always get an error. Either that the file is empty (though the $_FILES array contains the file data), or just an empty error... Help please....

Comment: You're posting back to a page under "wp-admin". I'm not a WordPress expert, but I would expect all pages under that path to be available only to authenticated (even admin) users. Maybe your upload page should be located under "wp-content".